# Lovely Ruby plugin Admin Design for .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, plugins, nuget-package

First, **sorry to post this non-programming** question but I have no idea where should I append this question into, [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), so I choose the one I most comfortable with.

---

I was trying to find a a nice **Admin Design** to have in a client project and to be used in more projects as it's almost all the same...

Tried to search the web but I was stumble upon this [Ruby Gem](http://activeadmin.info/).

[image]

http://activeadmin.info/

> Does anyone know if there's the same for .NET?

maybe a MVC 3.0 plug-in/nuGet?

---

Just to know, I would probably send an email to the developers **asking permission** to create a NuGet package for .NET using their current CSS and HTML, but I would prefer to know first that do all work and realize that one already existed, if it does, **I would gladly help extending it**.

Comment: balexandre, I would also gladly help extending on open source nuget package that is similar to active admin in mvc3. I stared a github repo https://github.com/eiu165/ActiveAdmin

Comment: Was this project started? It looks very promising. Specially the dashboard part of the interface.

Comment: Did this go anywhere? It would have been an awesome .net project

Comment: As for today this repo is empty.

Comment: @OferZelig nop, still there: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin

Comment: @balexandre I'm referring to eiu165's comment.

Comment: A colleague just put together a Ruby on Rails ActiveAdmin to edit records in a database in 20 minutes and it looks fantastic.  I'm surprised nothing similar exists for .Net.

Comment: Is there still nothing like this of the sorts? @balexandre did you try reaching out to the Active Admin team by chance? This project totally needs to exist!